# Array won't update with new values in while-loop

Tags: python, numpy

I am having a problem updating my x0x1 array with the new values in my while loop. When I print my array out to check each generation iteration, its printing out the same values each time (despite me getting different z vector values). Not sure why.

I am getting the z-values for each iteration in my for loop, but for some reason, my newly generated x0x1 arrays each generation of the while loop are not being updated.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random



def calculateFunctionValueMatrix(x0x1, N):
    
    functionValueArray = np.zeros((N-1, 1))
    
    for i in range(0, N-1):
        functionValueArray[i] = calculateFunctionValue(x0x1[i])
        
    return functionValueArray    
   



def calculateFunctionValue(x):
    
    
    function = (x[0]-1)**2 + 5*((x[1]-x[0]**2)**2)
    return function
   


def x0x1Array(N):
    
    x0x1 = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, size = (N-1,2))
    
    generateCandidateVector(x0x1)
           
            
def generateCandidateVector(x0x1):
   
    print(x0x1)
    K = 10
    F= 0.8
    N = 10
    generation = 1
    
    
    while generation <= K:
        
        for i in range(0, N-1):
            x0_ind, x1_ind, x2_ind = np.random.choice(len(x0x1), 3)
            x0 = x0x1[x0_ind]
            x1 = x0x1[x1_ind]
            x2 = x0x1[x2_ind]
            vectorZ = x0 + F*(x1-x2)
            print("this is vector", vectorZ)
            
            if(calculateFunctionValue(vectorZ) < calculateFunctionValue(x0x1[i])):
                vectorZ = x0x1[i]
                
                
            
            elif(calculateFunctionValue(vectorZ) > calculateFunctionValue(x0x1[i])):
                x0x1[i] = x0x1[i]
                
        print(x0x1)    
                
        if(np.std(calculateFunctionValueMatrix(x0x1, N)) < 0.01):
                print("Optimal Solution Found")
    
        generation = generation + 1         
             
        
 
def main():
   
    N=50
    x0x1Array(N)
    
   
    
main()
```

Comment: it would help if you presented a *minimal* example

Comment: Your `elif` clause doesn't do anything.  It is assigning a value to itself.

Comment: Fixed it. Managed to get it working.